# How can Naruto talk to the tailed beasts?

Tags: naruto

How could Naruto talk to the tailed beasts while fighting Tobi? Was it because he was friends with Kurama now? If yes, then how could he talk to 4 tails? Because at that time he hadn't befriended Kurama..

Comment: I guess, there exists a relam where all tail beast can communicate with each other, and naruto is able to enter in that realm. The thing about realm stated in realm when naruto is fighting against Madara.

Comment: It might be because He become friend with Kurama & as we know all tails are born from one 10 tail beast so it might be possible they can communicate in their physics. this is just my guess.

Comment: Wasn't it because he had part of their chakra? I'm pretty sure they mentioned something about Naruto having all of their chakra and all of them being able to talk to each other.

Answer (score 3):

All jinchuriki have a inner sanctum and it's like telepathy. When the tailed beast acknowledge Naruto as an ally and kind hearted person the share their chakra with him